# How to ordinalize a day using php?

Tags: php, date, date-format, date-arithmetic, ordinals

Using PHP I want to show the day of the month in ordinal way like ::

1   first
2   second
3   third
4   fourth
5   fifth
6   sixth
7   seventh
8   eighth
9   ninth
10  tenth
11  eleventh
12  twelfth
13  thirteenth
14  fourteenth
15  fifteenth
16  sixteenth
17  seventeenth
18  eighteenth
19  nineteenth
20  twentieth
21  twenty-first
22  twenty-second
23  twenty-third
24  twenty-fourth
25  twenty-fifth
26  twenty-sixth
27  twenty-seventh
28  twenty-eighth
29  twenty-ninth
30  thirtieth
31  thirty-first

e.g. 
if date is 22-Feb it should show : twenty-second Feb

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you already have your "array" there, just put it in code:

```
$ordinals = array(
    1=>"first",
    2=>"second",
    // ...
);
```

Then you can access the array:

```
echo $ordinals[date("d")];
```

Comment: So Simple but Excellent solution .....  !! I was trying to achieve this functionality using php date formats and functions...... This array concept doenst hit my mind once ! Cool.. U saved my day....